# How to compare array value with column in codeigniter database query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with php. I want to get values from database table by comparing a column. The problem is the value coming from html code to compare with column is checkbox value and array. I want something like it,
HTML

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="Audi">Audi<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="BMW">BMW<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="Ford">Ford<br>
```

and code in codeigniter model is
`$this->db->where('car_name ==', $car[]);
$this->db->get('cars');`

Comment: How do you save values within your database

Comment: $this->db->where_in('car_name',$cararray);

Comment: Yes, It's working with `$this->db->where_in('car_name', $car);`.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `where_in` -

```
$this->db->where_in('car_name', $car);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Ref:https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html